# como usar dois CAST mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

estou precisando converte o resultado de ponto para virgula, e a expressão já usa cast e não estou conseguindo unilos, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
CAST(TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM JSON_EXTRACT(`log_036`.`nfce`.`Post`, '$.ProdTot'))
        AS DECIMAL (18 , 2 ) cast(REPLACE(`log_036`.`nfce`.`Post`, '.', ',') as float )) AS `TotalProdutos`,
```

Comment: ou seja, preciso pegar o valor retornado e converta de 100.00 para 100,00, ou seja, trocar de ponto para virgula

Answer (score -2):

eu consegui fazer mais oe menos o que queria,

```
 CAST(REPLACE(CAST(TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM JSON_EXTRACT(`log_036`.`nfce`.`Post`, '$.ProdTot'))
            AS DECIMAL (18 , 2 )), '.', ',') AS FLOAT) AS `TotalProdutos`,
```

mas agora esta retornando sem casas decimais

7916

o resultado deveria ser 7916,85